# User Defined Datatype with Constraint in DB2

Tags: db2, user-defined-data-types

I want to create a user defined data type, let's call it  ‘MyPosInt’ which can take only positive integers within 1 to 100 as its value in DB2.

Now I know, I can create a user defined datatype using 'CREATE DATATYPE' query, but how do I impose this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

```
CREATE TYPE MyPosInt AS INTEGER WITH WEAK TYPE RULES
       CHECK(VALUE > 0 AND VALUE <= 100)
```

You will find more details in the [documentation](https://knowledgecenter.mybluemix.net/beta/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000913.html)

Comment: Thank you [@michaeltiefenbacher](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5959625/michaeltiefenbacher)! I also found this link to be useful [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/weak_type?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C3084758091&lang=en)